# Binary Tree - C code

Tags: tree

My problem is: I want to write a code that gets number from the user, put it on a binary tree and when the user types 0, print the tree in order. But, when I get, for example, 5 4 6 0, the correct result would be 4 5 6, but I get no output... Can anyone help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct TreeNode TreeNode;
struct TreeNode{
    int data;
    TreeNode* left;
    TreeNode* right;
};

TreeNode* newTree(){
    return NULL;
}

void insertNode(TreeNode* node, int value){
    if(node==NULL){
        TreeNode* tmp = malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
        tmp->data=value;
        tmp->left=NULL;
        tmp->right=NULL;
    }

    else{
        if(value > node->data){
            insertNode(node->right, value);
        }
        if(value < node->data){
            insertNode(node->left, value);
        }
    }
}

void inOrder(TreeNode* t){
    if(t==NULL){
        return;
    }
    else{
        inOrder(t->left);
        printf("%d\n", t->data);
        inOrder(t->right);
    }
}

int main(){
    TreeNode* root = malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
    TreeNode* aux;
    aux = newTree();
    root = newTree();
    int number, cont=0;

    while(1){
        printf("Type the number you want to add (0 to exit): ");
        scanf("%d", &number);
        if(number==0){
            printf("In order: \n");
            inOrder(root); 
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            insertNode(root, number);
        }
        cont++;
    }

}//end of main
```

Answer (score 0):

In your insert node function you're creating a new `tmp` node when the node you recieve from the parameter is NULL, but you never assign the pointer you sent as parameter `TreeNode* node` to the new node you created.

Another problem is performing malloc in the root node outside the insertNode function, as this will create a non-null node, without a `data` value. Then it'll enter the else in your function without any value to be compared, or worse, garbage. By removing it, the root node will be assigned as soon as you insert your first value, without any problems.

Finally, your insertNode should be passing the node by reference, in order to retain the new value it'll be assigned once malloc is performed, which would make the insert function look like this:

**Edit: realized the question asked for C, not C++, corrected the code**

```
void insertNode(TreeNode** node, int value){
    if(*node==NULL){
        TreeNode* tmp = malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
        tmp->data=value;
        tmp->left=NULL;
        tmp->right=NULL;
        *node = tmp;
    }

    else{
        if(value > (*node)->data){
            insertNode(&(*node)->right, value);
        }
        if(value < (*node)->data){
            insertNode(&(*node)->left, value);
        }
    }
}
```

And removing the malloc from the main function:

```
int main(){
    TreeNode* root = NULL;// = malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
    TreeNode* aux;
    aux = newTree();
    root = newTree();
    int number, cont=0;

    while(1){
        printf("Type the number you want to add (0 to exit): ");
        scanf("%d", &number);
        if(number==0){
            printf("In order: \n");
            inOrder(root); 
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            insertNode(&root, number);
        }
        cont++;
    }

}//end of main
```